# LWC - Check if the user have apex class access or not in LWC JS without making a server call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, permissions

The goal is to first check if we have access to that apex class or not, if access is available then only make an apex call.
I have come across [Check Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_get_permissions) but this doesn't state an check for an apex class.
May anyone please suggest something?
We have to check the access level for an apex class in JS without making an apex call.

Answer (score 2):

The "without a server call" is impossible, sadly. Your choices are to either make a server call to query the [SetupEntityAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm) object to see if the user has permission, or make the API call directly and examine the error you get back.